# Kafka consumer, which takes effect, max.poll.records or max.partition.fetch.bytes?

Tags: apache-kafka

I have trouble understand these two consumer settings, let's say I have a topic with 20 partitions, and all messages are 1KB size, and, to simplify this discussion, also suppose that I have only one consumer.

If I set max.partition.fetch.bytes=1024, then, since each partition will give me one message, I will get 20 messages in one go if I understanding it correctly.

But what if I set max.poll.records=10? Could anyone help to provide some explanation? Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no direct relation between two configs. `max.partition.fetch.bytes` specifies max amount data **per partition** the server will return. On the other hand `max.poll.records` specifies maximum number of records returned in a single **poll()**.

So in your case if you have a topic with 20 partitions that each of them has one record  with 1KB size and there is only one consumer which subscribes to this topic,
then you can get each of the messages because message size doesn't exceed `max.partition.fetch.bytes` but you can also get at most 10 messages in one poll.

As a result;

- Your consumer will get 10 messages in the first call to poll().
- In your second poll() it will get other 10 records.

Comment: Thank you, but still not very clear to me. So for that consumer,  which is the way it go? 1) go to 10 partitions to fetch 10 messages -> process them in the first poll -> go to the remainding 10 partitions to fetch another 10 messages -> process them in the second poll. Or 2) go to all partitions to fetch all 20 message -> process 10 in the first poll -> process the other 10 in the second poll.

Comment: "max.poll.records only controls the number of records returned from poll, but does not affect fetching. The consumer will try to prefetch records from all partitions it is assigned. It will then buffer those records and return them in batches of max.poll.records each (either all from the same topic partition if there are enough left to satisfy the number of records, or from multiple topic partitions if the data from the last fetch for one of the topic partitions does not cover the max.poll.records)."
source: https://groups.google.com/g/kafka-clients/c/5jagwTywVb8/m/2v7vYg9SBAAJ

Comment: @H.Ç.T - I was referring to [doc](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/configuration/consumer-configs.html#max-partition-fetch-bytes). It states something like `If the first record batch in the first non-empty partition of the fetch is larger than this limit, the batch will still be returned to ensure that the consumer can make progress.`. So in this case should not it get all the 20 records?